# convert Option[List[String]] to List[String]

Tags: list, scala

How do we convert `Option[List[String]]` to `List[String]` in Scala? I am trying to get a values from a Scala `Map` where key is a `String` and value is `List[String]`.
But when I get the value for the key, it is being returned as `Option[List[String]]`.

Comment: the question should not be how to get a list. it's returning an option because there is no other sane path. you first need to answer what the value should be if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use `getOrElse()` method on map like:

```
map.get(key).getOrElse(List.empty[String])
```

`getOrElse()` method return actual List[String] when `Key` is present in map otherwise it will return the `empty List[String]`.

One advantage of using `getOrElse()` method here is it makes your code more readable

Comment: A `Map` has a `getOrElse` method which is more efficient than doing it in two steps like this.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is

```
map.getOrElse(key, Nil)
```

If your code is inside a `Try` or other exception handler, or if you can *prove* that the key is there, then this is the alternative

```
map(key)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Option` can be turned into a list by calling `toList`, which you can then `flatten` to turn the list-of-lists into a single list:

```
map.get(key).toList.flatten
```

This will return `List[String]`. If you try to retrieve a key that does not exist in the map it will return an empty list.